# Select parent row cell value for child row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am importing data from an Excel sheet, and I am at a point where I have one table with parent and child rows. Child rows have around the same columns as the parent rows, except that the child row has null in column A, which is my primary key for the parent rows and my foreign key-to-be for the child row.

Sample data

```
 - AI ID | Employee Number | Employee Name
 - 1     | 33400           | John
 - 2     | NULL            | John's Wife
 - 3     | NULL            | John's Child
 - 4     | 43443           | Susan
 - 5     | NULL            | Susan's Husband
```

How can I fill the rows 2,3,4 Employee Number that have NULL with the values of their parent rows.

So that Employee Number column becomes like this

```
 - 33400
 - 33400
 - 33400
 - 43443
 - 43443
```

**Note: Update**
This is a real world scenario, so no field of the parent row is necessary identifying it's child rows. It's unfortunate the table above implies `employee name` to be doing so.

**What is actually** identifying child-parent row dependency is the `AI ID` column. Each child row belongs to the first row above it with `employer number NOT NULL` when all rows are ordered by `AI ID`. So ideally I was am looking at a query that does the following:

```
IF Employee_Number IS NULL
SELECT Employee_Number OF FIRST ROW
WHERE Employee_Number IS NOT NULL AND ROW_ABOVE.AI_ID < CURRENT_ROW.AI_ID
```

Something of the sorts above.

Comment: General note: The answers given below assume that the parent employee name is unique.  If this isn't the case, which _would_ most likely be the case for a real company, then these answers might not work as expected.  Ideally, your table would have a column called `parent` which would contain the ID of its parent employee.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, it's a real world scenario and unfortunately the employee name cannot be used in this case. I did not intend to imply so. I have added how I intend the query to tie child rows to parent rows. See Update.

Comment: Using the AI ID alone won't help here, because your table has no information about how those IDd are related to each other.

Comment: Hi, I've added an answer using AI_ID and a sub query to get the nearest parent row's `employee_number` above each child row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo Here: http://rextester.com/FDJYO55558

Have done the following, but I do not imply it to be efficient (resource wise) in any way since it uses a sub query. So for my purpose of a once off import exercise, this is just bare bones of what achieves what I want. If more efficient ways can come, I'ld be more than willing to learn!

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (`AI_ID` int, `Employee_Number` int, `Employee_Name` varchar(255));
INSERT INTO yourTable (`AI_ID`, `Employee_Number`, `Employee_Name`)
VALUES
(1, 33400, 'John'),
(2, NULL,  'John''s Wife'),
(3, NULL,  'John''s Child'),
(4, 43443, 'Susan'),
(5, NULL,  'Susan''s Husband');

SELECT *, 
(SELECT Employee_Number FROM yourTable innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.AI_ID <= outerTable.AI_ID
    AND innerTable.Employee_Number IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY innerTable.AI_ID DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS Parent_Employee_Number FROM yourTable outerTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.`AI ID`,
       t2.`Employee Number`,
       t1.`Employee Name`
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.`Employee Name` LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.`Employee Name`, '%')
WHERE t2.`Employee Number` IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

**Late edit:**

Seeing the answer by @Giorgos made me wonder whether you want to actually *update* your table.  If so, my query can be slightly modified to:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.`Employee Name` LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.`Employee Name`, '%')
SET t1.`Employee Number` = t2.`Employee Number`
WHERE t2.`Employee Number` IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: and what if several employee called "John"?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Then of course my query would break.  Ideally, we should be joining on some sort of ID/numerical column which represents a parent-child relationship.  For the purpose of this actual question, I think the OP just wants to see a general approach.

Comment: Yes. just let him (OP) know, that if employee names are not unique, (and child always contains parent name) this may be cause unexpected result

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like the following:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table1 AS t2 ON t1.EmployeeName LIKE CONCAT(t2.EmployeeName, '%')
SET t1.EmployeeNumber = t2.EmployeeNumber
WHERE t1.EmployeeNumber IS NULL
```

The query works as long as there is exactly one matching parent record for each child record based on the first part of `EmployeeName`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea9961/1)

Comment: Hi Giorgos, check our www.rextester.com , it's _way_ better and more reliable than SQL Fiddle, which is down half the time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the tip. I've already been using rextester for the past month. I first try sqlfiddle though due to its nice `text-to-ddl` feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do **more research** before you do this table update. It a usual case that we can have employees with the same names. In that case you will end up updating records having `NULL` employee number with incorrect `Employee Number`.

After your research, write a script with few sql statements to do the purpose than firing a single update. Don't miss taking backup of your table.